# How i can get Uri from intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I did

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        //если выбрали камеру - запускаем ее
        case R.id.b_camera:
            //uri = generateFileUri();
            if (uri == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.sdnot), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            //intentCamera.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intentCamera, PHOTO_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE);
        break;
    }
}
```

Method generateFileUri() is called in onCreateView().
Line intentCamera.putExtra("return-data", true); doesnot work for me (if use "return-data" as a key in onActivityResult at getParceble()).

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturned) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        //если результат пришел от камеры
        case PHOTO_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "result ok");
                //извлекаем uri фотки из интента
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturned.getData();
                Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "getdata works!");
                //создаем интент для запуска новой активити
                Intent last_intent_photo = new Intent(getView().getContext(), ViewPhoto.class);
                //помещаем в интент этот uri
                last_intent_photo.putExtra("fotka",selectedImage);
                //стартуем новую активити
                startActivity(last_intent_photo);

            } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED)
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Capture cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        default: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturned);

    }
}
```

I see log "result ok". I think it meens camera did work well.
But then i see: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:2, request=100, result=-1, data=null}. How it can be?!

Well, i tried Uri selectedImage = imageReturned.getExtras().getParcelable(); but i have not a key in my intent to put it into getParcelable(String key).

So, why result is ok, but data=null?

Comment: please, attach the code how you are starting the camera

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1:**

```
//Uri myUri = ...
intent.setData(myUri);
```

and

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
```

**Option 2:**

According to documentation:

> toString() - Returns the encoded string representation of this URI

```
//Uri myUri = ...
intent.putStringExtra("uri",myUri.toString());
```

and

```
String uriString = intent.getStringExtra("uri");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
```

Answer (score 3):

recently onActivityResult has been deprecated so because of that

```
private val getIntent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (it.data != null) {
                val imageUri = it.data!!.data as Uri
                val image = yourCustomMethod(imageUri)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you need to get the `uri` from `intert` since you are passing it youself? just use the same `uri` as:

```
intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

**UPD to clarify**:

when you're starting the cameta with option:

```
intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

you are telling to the camera that the photo must be stored in this path. so, if the result OK you need to get that photo by this uri.

```
 if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
    Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "result ok");

    // same as passed in intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    Uri selectedImage = uri; 

    Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "getdata works!");
    //создаем интент для запуска новой активити
    Intent last_intent_photo = new Intent(getView().getContext(), ViewPhoto.class);
    //помещаем в интент этот uri
    last_intent_photo.putExtra("fotka",selectedImage);
    //стартуем новую активити
    startActivity(last_intent_photo);
}
```

**UPD 2**

FragmentScaling.onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("uri")) {
        uri = (Uri)getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("uri");
    }
}
```

Comment: May be I do mistake, but i need after making photo open a new activity with this photo so in onAvtivityResult i have intent from camera, i take uri from this intent and make new intent for a new activity. Am i right?

Comment: I did it and now i have: I/HHHHHHHHHHHH: result ok
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                          Process: ru.bunakov.testapplication, PID: 8610                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.bunakov.testapplication/ru.bunakov.testapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:2, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity

Comment: In onActivityResult i check if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && imageReturned != null) but in logs i see: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=100, result=-1, data=null} How it can be?   //I added MainActivity code below

Comment: This does not answer the question, Neil's ans is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    //вызывается при создании активити
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PreferenceHelper.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext());
        preferenceHelper = PreferenceHelper.getInstance();

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        runSplash();

        setUI();
    }


    //метод для созданию интерфейса
    private void setUI(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null){
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_list_white_18dp).setText(R.string.listtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_white_18dp).setText(R.string.scalingtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_web_asset_white_18dp).setText(R.string.parsingtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_location_white_18dp).setText(R.string.maptab));

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(fragmentManager, 4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can not even imagine where exactly to look for the error ...

```
//получаем результат из галереи или камеры
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturned) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        //если результат пришел от камеры
        case PHOTO_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && imageReturned != null) {
                Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "result ok"); // появляется в логе
                //извлекаем uri фотки из интента
                Uri selectedImage = uri;
                Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHH", "getdata works!"); //в логе не появляется!
                //создаем интент для запуска новой активити
                Intent last_intent_photo = new Intent(getView().getContext(), ViewPhoto.class);
                //помещаем в интент этот uri
                last_intent_photo.putExtra("fotka", selectedImage);
                //стартуем новую активити
                startActivity(last_intent_photo);

            } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED)
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Capture cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        default: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturned);

    }
}
```

Comment: давай на русском) когда ты вызываешь `intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);` ты говоришь чтобы картинка сохранилась по этому `uri`, если пришел `RESULT_OK` значит картинка сохранилась по этому `url`. Если падает ошибка пришли весь стектрейс

Comment: I/HHHHHHHHHHHH: result ok
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.bunakov.testapplication, PID: 12877
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:1, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {ru.bunakov.testapplication/ru.bunakov.testapplication.MainActivity}:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3680)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference at ru.bunakov.testapplication.fragments.FragmentScaling.onActivityResult(FragmentScaling.java:91)

Comment: этот метод прикрепи FragmentScaling.onActivityResult

Comment: Я уже туплю. куда его прикреплять?

Comment: к этому посту прикрепи.

Comment: не может в этом методе упасть `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference`. Запусти еще раз программу, сделай фото, вернись. Потом прикрепи полностью стектрейс с ошибкой

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: ru.bunakov.testapplication, PID: 20318
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at ru.bunakov.testapplication.fragments.FragmentScaling.onActivityCreated(FragmentScaling.java:142)

Comment: `// Save the activity state when it's going to stop.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (uri != null) {
            outState.putString("uri", uri.toString());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("uri")) {
           uri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("uri"));
        }
    }`

Comment: не понял как тут красиво код вставлять в комменты. 142 строка это: if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("uri"))

Comment: смотри UPD2 в моем посте

Comment: Отработал тост "Capture failed" в FragmentScaling из метода onActivityResult

Comment: убери это условие `&& imageReturned != null`

Comment: не помогло. та же фигня ((

Comment: может по этому `uri` уже есть картинка?

Comment: метод который генерирует название основан на времени. думаю, нет

Comment: вообщем не знаю дружище, этот пост про другой вопрос. я не могу весь день тут сидеть искать где у тебя ошибки. создавай новые посты

Comment: кстати в галерее фотки не появляются. значит фотки не сохраняются?

Comment: ладно, понял. спасибо за участие!

Comment: да, можешь поставить плюс и пометить вопрос как правильный. удачи!